# virtualbox dynamically allocated storage

Tags: virtualbox

What am I doing wrong, I created a 20 dynamically allocated storage, I tried to transfer a 3 gig file from memory key  and says not enough space. when i enter 
df -h it looks like I have no space. I'm new to this what did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I was booting live, once I did a graphical install all the drive space I was looking for was there.